# Display partials based on routes - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My routes looks like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
          controller: 'PageCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
          controller: 'PageCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/home'
      });
}]);
```

My View file looks like this:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <!-- show below nav section if I am on "home" page-->
    <nav class="menu-for-home">
      <h1>menus when on home page</h1>
    </nav>
    <!-- show below nav section if I am on "about" page-->
    <nav class="menu-for-about">
      <h1>menus when on about page</h1>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="main-body-container-wrap" data-ng-view >
    <!-- NgViews will be rendered here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see in above code, I have two different nav sections, later I will move them into separate partials, I like to load those partials depending on which page currently I am on.

Comment: Why not put the header section specific to that page into `home.html` and `about.html`? This would be the simplest solution unless your routes and pages are much more complicated than the example you have provided.

Comment: @Brett I don't want nav section come with in "main-body-container-wrap" class I have defined.

Comment: then put the ng-view directive on the body, since the whole body changes depending on the view.

Comment: I'd use ui-router and take advantage of states and multiple views.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and ng-hide based on a $scope variable inside PageCtrl. Or maybe [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) if you think your menus will grow...

Something like:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <!-- show below nav section if I am on "home" page-->
    <nav class="menu-for-home" data-ng-show="showHome">
      <h1>menus when on home page</h1>
    </nav>
    <!-- show below nav section if I am on "about" page-->
    <nav class="menu-for-about" data-ng-hide="showHome">
      <h1>menus when on about page</h1>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="main-body-container-wrap" data-ng-view >
    <!-- NgViews will be rendered here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Or with ng-switch:

```
<body>
  <header ng-switch="currentHeader">
    <!-- show below nav section if I am on "home" page-->
    <nav class="menu-for-home" data-ng-switch-default>
      <h1>menus when on home page</h1>
    </nav>
    <!-- show below nav section if I am on "about" page-->
    <nav class="menu-for-about" data-ng-switch-when="about">
      <h1>menus when on about page</h1>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="main-body-container-wrap" data-ng-view >
    <!-- NgViews will be rendered here -->
  </div>
</body>
```